# Two rows in a table into single row

Tags: sql-server

```
Type            TableName       TableRowCount  
Source          table_1         1
Destination     table_1         3
Source          table_2         10
Destination     table_2         5

SourceTableName  SourceTableRowCount     DestinationTableName  DestinationTableRowCount
--------------  -------------------      --------------------   ------------------------
table_1             1                       table_1                 3
table_2             10                      table_2                 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
select t1.TableName As SourceTableName, t1.SourceTableRowCount as SrcCnt, t2.TableName as DestinationTableName, t2.TableRowCount as DestinationTableRowCount from test t1
left join test t2 on t2.Type != t1.Type and t2.TableName = t1.TableName 
where t2.Type = 'Destination'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inner join` to get your desired result. First filter your result in different set of records as needed, then combine them on the basis of join on your base value, in this case which is your `tablename`.

```
; with cte as (
select TableName as SourceTableName, TableRowCount as SourceTableRowCount from yourtable 
where type = 'source'
)
, ct as (
select TableName as DestinationTableName, TableRowCount as DestinationTableRowCount from yourtable 
where type = 'Destination'
)
select * from cte inner join ct on cte.SourceTableName = ct.DestinationTableName
```